# how to add event in dataGrid in C#

Tags: c#

Consider i have a dataGrid that is created dynamically. Now i need to add an event, i.e load another form when i click a specific cell in the dataGrid. How can i do this in C# VS 2005.?

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? Wpf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `yourobject.NameOfEvent += new NameOfEventHandler(method);`